# ActionScript Lifecycle and how it works

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have just started using ActionScript. and i want to know the Lifecycle of that and also the properties used in that so please Help me by providing any valuable Link.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this site. May be you can get your answer there:

http://www.dlgsoftware.com/primers/Primer_on_Flex3_Component_Lifecycle.htm

Comment: Keep in mind that the Flex component lifecycle does not apply to objects in pure ActionScript projects. So for example if you develop a game, using Sprite and MovieClip objects, the above link does not apply.